# Setting the GLSL version on Mac

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl

How does one go about setting the GLSL version on Mac? Is this even possible? I'm running a fragment shader and would like to create an array of vec3s, but the shader compiler is producing an error indicating that I need to use a higher GLSL version. The specific error is

```
'array of 3-component vector of float' : array type not supported here in glsl < 120
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I have no Mac experience, you can specify the lowest required version of your shader (which is 1.10 by default, I think) by using something like

```
#version 120      //shader requires version 1.20
```

as first line in your shader. But of course the specified version also has to be supported by your hardware and driver, which you can check for with `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)`.

**EDIT:** I confirmed this with a look into the GLSL spec, which also says that all shaders that are linked together should target the same version, although I'm quite sure I myself have once successfully violated this, but this may be due to my forgiving nVidia driver. So if it still complains when linking, add the same `#version` tag to the vertex shader, too.